# Using PowerShell Split & regex to return everything after a regex match

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

Going through PowerShell logs, I'm attempting to extract the commands while discarding the path the command was ran from. For example,

`PS C:\Windows\system32> pwd`

I'd only like to return `pwd`. I know this can be accomplished with `.split`, but I'm struggling to get the regex working. The path will vary, so building a regex off a specific path will not work. My attempt right now is to match the string between "PS" and "> ", such as the regex here `(?<=(PS)).*(?=(> ))`. However this causes unintended results when the path has the letters 'ps' in it.

Splitting off of `>` is not wanted either, since if a command has `>` in it then I don't want to trim the actual command.

Comment: Split at the first occurence of `>`? `$command.Substring($command.IndexOf(">") + 1)`

Comment: I guess that works. I supposed I was overthinking it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply take the line, split it and take the last - no regex required if you want it that way

```
(("PS C:\Windows\system32> pwd") -split "> ",2)[-1]
```

Not the best regex, but will do the job:

```
("PS C:\Windows\system32> pwd") -replace "^.*?> ",""
```

Edit: changed regex as mentioned in comment - escaping unnecessary for ">"

Comment: There is no point escaping a `>` char in any regex flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to use RegEx to do the extracting of the command?

Try this:

```
$Line = 'PS C:\Windows\system32> pwd'
if($Line -match '(?i)ps [a-z]:(?:\\[a-z0-9]+)+>(?<Cmd>.*)') {
    $Matches.Cmd
}
```

Returns  `pwd`.  Place a space between `>(` to remove the leading space.